# I have an alert that pops up on specific days of the month but I need the alert to skip over weekends

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the alert to skip over the weekends only? I tried using `DayOfWeek` but the code doesn't seem to be reading it. 
detailed code snippet: (You can ignore this snippet, it's too detailed and outdated)

```
int staffId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAssign.SelectedValue);
    int d1, d3, d5; 
    var staff = BLL.FindStaffByID(staffId);
    var alert = false;

    var deadline = DateTime.Today;
    var Day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        if (txtDeadline.Text != "")
        {
            deadline = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDeadline.Text);
        }

    var bin = new ScheduleBin();
    bin.PackBins(staffId);
    var k1 = bin.PercentBusy(1);
    d1 = k1;
        if (d1 >= 100)
        {
            if (deadline == DateTime.Today || deadline == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
            {
                if (Day == DayOfWeek.Saturday || Day == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    alert = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert = true;
                }
            }
        }

    var k3 = bin.PercentBusy(3);
    d3 = k3;
        if (d3 >= 100)
        {
            if (deadline == DateTime.Today.AddDays(3))
            {
                if (Day == DayOfWeek.Saturday || Day == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    alert = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert = true;
                }
            }
        }

    var k5 = bin.PercentBusy(5);
    d5 = k5;
        if (d5 >= 100)
        {
            if (deadline == DateTime.Today || deadline == DateTime.Today.AddDays(7))
            {
                if (Day == DayOfWeek.Saturday || Day == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    alert = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert = true;
                }
            }
        }

    if (alert)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Whoa there! Looks like " + staff.FirstName + " is a bit booked for that deadline (" + d1 + "% | " + d3 + "% | " + d5 + "%). Check out their task list and talk to the AE's to see about clearing out some room, or consider assigning the task to someone else. \");</script>", false);
    }
```

Half the time I try using the `DayOfWeek` I get this error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.DateTime.DayOfWeek.get.
```

I was wondering what this error means exactly?

Shorter summary of code:

```
var alert = false;
var currentDay = DateTime.Today;

if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() != "Saturday" || DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() != "Sunday")
{
   if (currentDay == DateTime.Today || currentDay == DateTime.Today.AddDays(3))
   {
      alert = true;
   }
   else
   {
      alert = false;
   }
}

if (alert)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert(\"ALERT MESSAGE\");</script>", false);
}
```

Apologies for any confusion.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: One step to figuring this out is to put just this datetime logic in its own function. Name the function carefully according to what you want it to return. Name the inputs carefully. Don't use `DateTime.Today` in the function. Pass a date into the function. That will make the problem clearer because it's just in one place. You might find that the answer jumps right out at you. But if it doesn't, then you can post just that function here, and it will be much easier for everyone to see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your 2nd snippet doesn't set dayVal to anything in particular.  Your first code snippet...can't be used by anyone else to reproduce your problem.  And...is crazy unclear in purpose, tbh.  `DayOfWeek` certainly works, so barring some time zone issue, you are looking at a bug.  Stepping through in a debugger, or attempting some of the simplifications others have mentioned would be a good start.

Comment: do your switch case statement with a range of case on  the following `case: "Saturday" case: "Sunday" { alert = false; break;}` you can have your case default: { alert = true; break;} you are making this harder than it should be

Comment: The value of dayVal above would be 1900-01-01 00:00:00.
@MethodMan...DayOfWeek is an emum

Comment: Yeah the switch statement I had taken out because I was just setting it to an empty object, but I posted it just to get the general idea across. Same with the first snippet.  I’m sure it’s unclear because the first half is referring to a class in another .cs file, but those don’t need to be taken into account very much because my problem was only in the logic mainly, although yeah I did put a little more information than necessary.  Just in a nutshell, I’ve been having issues with DayOfWeek because the code runs everything except that portion.  I appreciate your input though!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the logic needs to be simplified; there could be multiple cases where alert is being set, not just one. In addition, if the current day of the week is a weekend, don't apply any of the other logic because it doesn't matter.

```
int staffId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAssign.SelectedValue);
var staff = BLL.FindStaffByID(staffId);
var alert = false;

var deadline = DateTime.Today;
var day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDeadline.Text))
    deadline = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDeadline.Text);

/* Only perform logic if it's not a weekend */
if (day != DayOfWeek.Saturday && day != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{       
    var bin = new ScheduleBin();
    bin.PackBins(staffId);

    /*Note inclusion of else statement to short circuit the logic */
    if (bin.PercentBusy(1) >= 100 && (deadline == DateTime.Today || deadline == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)))
    {
        alert = true;
    }
    else if (bin.PercentBusy(3) >= 100 && (deadline == DateTime.Today.AddDays(3)))
    {
        alert = true;
    }
    else if (bin.PercentBusy(5) >= 100 && (deadline == DateTime.Today || deadline == DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)))
    {
        alert = true;
    }

    if (alert)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Whoa there! Looks like " + staff.FirstName + " is a bit booked for that deadline (" + d1 + "% | " + d3 + "% | " + d5 + "%). Check out their task list and talk to the AE's to see about clearing out some room, or consider assigning the task to someone else. \");</script>", false);
    } 
}
```

Logically, this could be reduced to the following

```
var day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

/* Only perform logic if it's not a weekend */
if (day != DayOfWeek.Saturday && day != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
    var deadline = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDeadline.Text)
        ? Convert.ToDateTime(txtDeadline.Text)  
        :DateTime.Today;

    var bin = new ScheduleBin();
    int staffId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAssign.SelectedValue);
    bin.PackBins(staffId);

    var alert = (bin.PercentBusy(1) >= 100 && (deadline == DateTime.Today || deadline == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
        || bin.PercentBusy(3) >= 100 && (deadline == DateTime.Today.AddDays(3))
        || bin.PercentBusy(5) >= 100 && (deadline == DateTime.Today || deadline == DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)));

    if (alert)
    {
        var staff = BLL.FindStaffByID(staffId);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Whoa there! Looks like " + staff.FirstName + " is a bit booked for that deadline (" + d1 + "% | " + d3 + "% | " + d5 + "%). Check out their task list and talk to the AE's to see about clearing out some room, or consider assigning the task to someone else. \");</script>", false); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this was actually what I tried first but my logic was a little different, so I’ll give this a shot. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Never noticed the .AddDays method before.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar ...try something like this.

```
 private void CheckTime(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     switch (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString())
     {
        case "Saturday":
           {
              DoSomething();
              break;
           }
        case "Sunday":
           {
              DoNothing();
              break;
           }
     }
  }
```

Comment: the OP states they want to skip the weekends if I am reading the question correctly, so even in your case statement you can stack the case: "Saturday
case: "Sunday" { break;} it's called a `range` this does not appear to be an answer

Comment: Yeah I tried multiple usage of the switch statement but for some reason it doesn’t seem to read the DayOfWeek being specified.  Thank you for your input though!

Comment: Yeah I apologize, I’m not all too familiar with ranges just yet.  But thank you!